# BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION causes infinite recursion

Tags: c++, exception, boost

I'm using boost 1.53.0, and have had no problems up to this point (and have used sockets, timers, containers, algorithm, all without trouple).

I love the idea of using boost exceptions, especially because of the line number and what not.

however, in my (super simple) code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>

struct my_error: virtual boost::exception, virtual std::exception { };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(my_error());
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    std::cout <<"fail";
  }
}
```

Project generated with CMAKE (hopefully that's not screwing it up)

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project(error_test)
IF(WIN32)
   set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
   set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON) 
   set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
   set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS FALSE)
ENDIF()

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system date_time)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )



add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Instead of throwing, BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION enters an infinite recursion!

The compiler even catches this, stating a compiler warning

warning C4717: 'boost::exception_detail::throw_exception_' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow.

and it just keeps hitting:

```
test.exe!boost::exception_detail::throw_exception_<my_error>(const my_error & x, const char * current_function, const char * file, int line)  Line 84 + 0xd1 bytes  C++
```

I am using visual studio 2010 (win 64). I built boost using the following command, if that helps:

```
.\b2 install --prefix=C:\devtools\boost_1_53_0 --toolset=msvc --build-type=complete --build-dir=C:\devtools\bin\boost_1_53_0 address-model=64 architecture=x86
```

EDIT Adding expanded macros:

looks like the macro expands to

```
 ::boost::exception_detail::throw_exception_(my_error(), __FUNCSIG__  ,"main.cpp",40);
```

which expands to

```
 throw_exception_( E const & x, char const * current_function, char const * file, int line )
 {
     ::boost::exception_detail::throw_exception_(set_info( set_info( set_info( enable_error_info(x), throw_function(current_function)), throw_file(file)), throw_line(line)), __FUNCSIG__  ,"C:\\devtools\\boost_1_53_0\\boost/throw_exception.hpp",91);
```

#line 92 "C:\devtools\boost_1_53_0\boost/throw_exception.hpp"
     }

Comment: Can you give a complete minimal working example, including header files, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just plain weird. As you can easily check at https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/tags/release/Boost_1_53_0/boost/throw_exception.hpp boost::exception::throw_exception_ is not not recursive at all.

The only way I can see such a thing happening is with evil macros. Please try putting this in your main file, before and after every include directive.

```
#if defined(throw_exception) || defined(throw_exception_)
#error Somebody set us up the bomb
#endif
```

Comment: boost::throw_exception is fine, however it does not add the __LINE__ info ect. Its the BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION macro that's giving me problems. The infinite loop is in the 'exception_detail::throw_exception_'. It calls another BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION. I'll expand out the macros and add it to my question, so we can clearly see the problem.

Comment: Also, I should state that I confirmed that nobody "set us up the bomb"

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and give you answer credit because the "You broke something" was actually dead on.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it looks like for some reason

```
    throw_exception_( E const & x, char const * current_function, char const * file, int line )
    {
        boost::throw_exception(
            set_info(
                set_info(
                    set_info(
                        enable_error_info(x),
                        throw_function(current_function)),
                    throw_file(file)),
                throw_line(line)));
    }
```

was changed to

```
    throw_exception_( E const & x, char const * current_function, char const * file, int line )
    {
        BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(
            set_info(
                set_info(
                    set_info(
                        enable_error_info(x),
                        throw_function(current_function)),
                    throw_file(file)),
                throw_line(line)));
    }
```

in my code...so I must have broken my own boost build. Sorry about the wild goose chase! I voted to close this thread...